# How to calculate moving/rolling average in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns, moving-average

I have yearly data (day wise) in my SQL table. I want to calculate 3 months rolling/moving average.How this can be done?

Comment: Average of what? And where this will be done - in function or procedure. or view? Basically, you should take a look to DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions.

Comment: If on SQL2012 take a look at [this](http://stevestedman.com/2012/03/rows-preceding-and-following-in-tsql-2012/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will give you an advise.

```
drop table #temp

;with cte as
(
    select 1 as id
    union all
    select id + 1 from cte
    where id < 100
)
select 
    *, id / 10 as "year", null as "rolSum"
into #temp
from 
    cte 
where 
    id < 100

select "year", id from #temp order by "year"


declare @rolSum int = 0
update #temp set @rolSum = "rolSum" = @rolSum + id from #temp

select year, id, rolSum, avg( id * 1.0 ) over ( partition by "year" order by id ) from #temp
```

`rolSum` is just included for further processing if `avg(...)` does not fulfill your needs.